# Are there any disbelievers among the animals?

Tags: animals

Are there anyone who doesn't believe in Allaah or denies his worship or remembrance among the animal kingdom?

Comment: That's a funny question although I'd think dolphins would come close to animals who have a mind of their own and thereby can choose freely what they believe in. But it's hard to prove or disprove scientifically they have such a kind of developed brain that they could choose what they believe in.

Answer (score 3):

There are a quite a few ayahs from the Quran relevant to this topic. Some of them are:

> They say, " Allah has taken a son." Exalted is He! Rather, **to Him
>   belongs whatever is in the heavens and the earth. All are devoutly
>   obedient to Him** [Quran 2:116](https://quran.com/2/116)

and

> Do you not see that Allah is exalted by whomever is within the heavens
>   and the earth and [by] the birds with wings spread [in flight]? **Each
>   [of them] has known his [means of] prayer and exalting [Him], and
>   Allah is Knowing of what they do.** [Quran 24:41](https://quran.com/24/41-42)

and

> Indeed, **We subjected the mountains [to praise] with him [David],
>   exalting [ Allah ]** in the [late] afternoon and [after] sunrise. And
>   **the birds were assembled, all with him repeating [praises]**. [Quran
>   38:18-19](https://quran.com/38/16-26?translations=20)

A major difference between humans/jinns and other creations in that we have been granted free will/choice. We can ***choose to obey or disobey Allah***, whereas animals cannot. Everything that they do is a worship to Allah.

> And **I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me.** I do
>   not want from them any provision, nor do I want them to feed
>   Me.Indeed, it is Allah who is the [continual] Provider, the firm
>   possessor of strength. [Quran 51:56-58](https://quran.com/51)

Beyond this amount of knowledge that we have, only Allah knows.

Answer (score 0):

None, because the do not have any choice, or enough intelligence to make a free will choice, as is the case with human being.

Comment: This answer would benefit from evidences supporting your claims. See [answer].